# How to compare two different data type variables in where condition of SQL query

Tags: sql

I have one column which is `integer` in first table and second is `varcha`. Now I need to compare these 2 variables which are of different data types and retrieve data if it matches.

Please could please help me out how to work on this?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? The casting/converting functions are different between systems.

Answer (score 2):

Please specify which DBMS you're using please.

Sql Server?
[CAST / CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

EDIT:

Well, I see you mentioned Sql*Plus above which to me says Oracle so for the sake of thoroughness. CAST appears to be what you're looking for. CONVERT does something a bit different in Oracle so you'd be doing something like

```
CAST(@YourStringValue AS INTEGER) = @YourOtherIntegerValue
```

or whatever datatype you want to cast your column to and then compare it against your other value. **The syntax may be off a bit as I'm no Oracle guy** but this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If it is about MS SQL, then it will cast those for you implicitly, no need to cast or convert.

```
declare @IntVariable int
set @IntVariable = 3

declare @VarcharVariable varchar(10)
set @VarcharVariable = '3'

select case when @IntVariable = @VarcharVariable then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either cast varchar to int or int to varchar and then compare.

Short example of casting:

```
CAST(ColumnName as datatype)as CertainName
```

Here `CertainName` means u can show that to display as your new column name

Comment: i used this one,but its not workin giving me an erros as missing expression

Answer (score 0):

if yo are using c# java or other strict type programming languase then you will have to convert the int type into string then you will be able to compare them if you are using PHP then no conversion will be required